# Unbiased Estimator based on Sufficient Statistic

Tags: self-study, inference, unbiased-estimator, sufficient-statistics, umvue

suppose $X_1, ... , X_n$  are iid with pdf
$f(x|\beta) = e^{-(x-\beta))}I_{(\beta, \infty)}(x)$

and the pdf of ( the smallest order statistic) $X_{(1)}$ is given by

$f_{X_1}(x)$ =  n $ *$ $e^{n(\beta-x)}$ ,  $\beta \leq x$

> Question is below:

If our goal is to find a function of $X_{(1)}$  , for example    $g(X_{(1)})$ so that , that function is unbiased estimator of $\beta$.

which means we want $E_{\beta}[g(X_{(1)})]$ = $\beta$

where $E_{\beta}[g(X_{(1)})]$ $=$ $\int_{\theta}^{\infty}g(x)f_{X_1}(x)dx $ $=$$\int_{\beta}^{\infty}(x)*n*e^{n(\beta-x)}dx $ = **$\beta$ $+$ $\frac{1}{n}$**
is the last calculation of the integral right?

also does that mean  that an unbiased estimator of $\beta$ which is  a function of  $X_{(1)}$ equals to

$g(X_{(1)})$ =  $X_{(1)}$ $-$ $\frac{1}{n}$ ? ?

Comment: Also answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/113642/119261.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X_i-\beta$ are i.i.d $\mathsf{Exp}(1)$, we have $\min_i(X_i-\beta)=X_{(1)}-\beta\sim \mathsf{Exp}$ with mean $1/n$.

Your conclusion is correct, but there is no need for guesswork. Just work out $E\left[X_{(1)}\right]$ from the pdf of $X_{(1)}$, i.e. find $\int xf_{X_{(1)}}(x)\,dx$ directly. If you are starting with $E_{\beta}\left[g(X_{(1)})\right]=\beta$, then you have to differentiate this equation with respect to $\beta$ to solve for $g(\cdot)$, which of course gives the same answer.

Comment: One more question please. Is t true that the MLE of  $e^{\beta}$ is $e^{X_{(1)}}$ since  $f(x|\beta) = e^{-(x-\beta))}I_{(\beta, \infty)}(x)$.                                                             ( also MLE of of  ${\beta}$  is $X_{(1)}$

Comment: MLE of $\beta$ is $X_{(1)}$, so yes that is correct by invariance of MLE.