# How to check if an estimator is unbiased?

Tags: r, distributions, self-study, unbiased-estimator

Given random sample $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ with the distribution function $$f(x|\theta) = \left \{ \begin{aligned} e^{-(x-\theta)}, \ \ \theta < x < \infty \\ 0, \text{ otherwise.} \end{aligned} \right.  $$

where $\theta \in (-\infty, \infty).$ Show that the estimator $\theta_1 = \min\left\{X_1, X_2, ..., X_n \right\} $ is unbiased. I only got as far as defining $\theta_1 = \mathrm{function}(sample) \ \ \min(sample)$, what should I do next?

Comment: Why do you think  $e^{-(x-\theta)}, \ \ 0 < x < \theta $ is a density function?

Comment: I don't see how $\theta_1$ could possibly be unbiased, because when $\theta \gt 0$ it is guaranteed to be less than $\theta$!  Also, it makes no sense to write "$0\lt x\lt \theta$" when $\theta$ is negative. You must have a typo (or several) somewhere in your question--please fix it.

Comment: @whuber I fixed it.

Comment: @Masoud That is not the case whenever $\theta$ is negative.  use1883: you can find the distribution of $\theta_1$ explicitly.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/406181/119261

Answer (score 2):

I assume  $X_i$ are independent. So

$Y=\min (X_1,\cdots X_n) $

$$F_Y(y)=1-P(Y>y)=1-P(X_1>y,\cdots, X_n>y)=1-e^{-n(y-\theta)}$$
so

$$f_Y(y)=ne^{-n(y-\theta)} \hspace{1cm} \theta < y$$

so $E(Y)=\theta + \frac{1}{n}$.

That is, $\min (X_1,\cdots X_n)$ is biased.

Comment: Could you explain why you assume $\theta$ is positive?

Comment: I think this is right also if $\theta\in (-\infty , \infty)$

Comment: $X-\theta$ is exponential distribution. so $\theta \in R$

Comment: @masoud How did you arrived at expected value for Y? Also in this case Y is minimum of each sample, but what is y?

Comment: $Y-\theta$ has exponential distribution,$Exponential(n)$, so$E(Y-\theta)=\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: $Y$ is a random variable, but $y$ is a number(an observation of random variable)